# IE Automation Run-time Error '91' - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I want to run a report in IE and for that, I need to update an element field.

I used `IE.document.getElementsByName("Field id per the inspect element")(0).Value = Prop` which I usually do, but VBA is throwing an error stating "object variable or with block not set in vba".

I have other codes where I used the same to update the element fields without any error.

```
Option Explicit    
Public IE As InternetExplorer

Sub Test()    
Dim Prop As String

Prop = "._rpt1^._ibp"

Set IE = Nothing
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.yardipcu.com/44812lennarsso/pages/menu.aspx?sMenuSet=len_iData_int"
Do While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

IE.document.getElementsByName("PropLookup:Lookup")(0).Value = Prop
'here I receive the error
IE.document.forms(0).submit

End sub
```

Comment: Are you sure a field with this name exists on the specified page? If you browse to the page with a browser, can you see it in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Try what you get from ```IE.document.getElementsByName("Field id per the inspect element")``` - it returns empty array as per your code.

Comment: We need to see the url and/or the html in question. You can share the relevant html using snippet tool via [edit].

Comment: Based on your code, you are trying to use HTML element ID to search the element by it's tag name. if you already have an ID than try to search an element using it's ID like IE.document.getElementByID("Field id per the inspect element").Value = Prop Let us know in which HTML element you are trying to set the value. Also inform us, which version of IE and which OS you are using for making this test may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @QHarr here you go, I made the changes as requested.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I searched the element by its ID and not by tag name. the element I tried using is "PropLookup:Lookup" which I got from the developer tools. I use IE11 on Windows 10.

Comment: If you see your code than you can notice that you are using Getelementsbyname and you are trying pass an ID of the element. Is the site address correct which you are using in your original post? I try to check it and find that it is not exist on the internet. Please try to check it. If it is correct than try to provide your HTML code. We will try to make a test with it to check for the issue.